# Datajoint Lost Connection Error (Server connection lost due to an interface error)

Tags: python, server, interface, connection, datajoint

I am running datapoint in Pycharm on a Mac. When I am connecting to the Database via the Pycharm Terminal, I can execute the code. Also, using the Pycharm Python Console, I am able to connect to the database. However, here, when I want to execute code or have a look at tables, it raises the error "Datajoint Lost Connection Error (Server connection lost due to an interface error)". Does anyone know, why this might be/ How to solve this problem?

I have tried to connect to other datajoint databanks, but it raises the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm less familiar with PyCharm, it is the case with Jupyter/IPython terminals that the connection will lapse after a timeout. By restarting the kernel, you can re-establish this connection.

If this is a consistent issue with certain time-intensive `autopopulate` tables, I would recommend breaking down `make` functions into separate pieces across multiple tables.